# Как отключить слеш в конце одиночных тегов?

Tags: html, xml, visual-studio-code, tag, prettier

Как отключить слеш в конце одиночных тегов html, при форматировании кода, Prettier - Code formatte?
[image: Выделено красным прямоугольником!]

Comment: В Prettier никак. Можно использовать другой форматтер.

Comment: Это плохо). Я вот использовал Beautify плагин, Но там я не могу  убрать межстрочные пробелы при форматировании.

Comment: [issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5641) существует с 2018 года, походу это их дизайн решение

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, а на кой их убирать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения этого вопроса, если это нужно для `пет-проекта` можно применить небольшой патч.Как вариант, если не нравится патч, можно сделать билд версии (для своих нужд)

**Для патча:**

Найти в файле `node_modules/prettier/index.js` такую строку `if (node.isSelfClosing)` и заменить `return "/>";` на `return ">";`

Это решение основано на исследовании исходников версии `2.9.0` а проверено на версии `^2.8.1`

**Для билда:**

`prettier/src/language-html/print/tag.js`

```
function printClosingTagEndMarker(node, options) {
  if (shouldNotPrintClosingTag(node, options)) {
    return "";
  }
  switch (node.type) {
    case "ieConditionalComment":
    case "ieConditionalEndComment":
      return "[endif]-->";
    case "ieConditionalStartComment":
      return "]><!-->";
    case "interpolation":
      return "}}";
    case "element":
      if (node.isSelfClosing) {
        return "/>";  <--------------------- править тут
      }
    // fall through
    default:
      return ">";
  }
}
```

*Это не самый лучший вариант, во фремворках нужны само-закрывающиеся теги, но это потребует больше правок в исходниках.*